# jQuery parse string before that symbols "{" "}" (different language on site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, text

i need to grab some text that is between that { }
But we have 3 languages same time

f.e 
**{:en}Resources List{:}{:ru}Список Ресурсов{:}{:uk}Список Ресурсів{:}**

So if we have english version now, we need to show what is between {:en} some text {:}

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: if language is RU f.e, we shall show only the text which is in {:ru} %TEXT% {:}

Comment: This is not a question. You are simply describing your requirements. You should try something on your own and ask more specific **programming** question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

No need jQuery. Use regex

```
var str = "{:en}Resources List{:}{:ru}Список Ресурсов{:}{:uk}Список Ресурсів{:}";
var regex = new RegExp("{:en}([^{]*){:}"); // english
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match[1]); // "Resources List"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use just plain old js

```
var langs = "{:en}Resources List{:}{:ru}Список Ресурсов{:}{:uk}Список Ресурсів{:}";
var languageTranslations = langs.split('{:}');
languageTranslations.pop(); // this will remove the last empty string element
```

the above code will result an array like this :

```
 ["{:en}Resources List", "{:ru}Список Ресурсов", "{:uk}Список Ресурсів"]
```

Now you can parse each of them easily like

```
languageTranslations.map(function(item){  
 var firstIndexOf = item.indexOf('}');   
 var translation = item.substr(firstIndexOf +1 );
 var language =  item.substr(2,firstIndexOf -2);
 return { text : translation , language : language };
});
```

The above code will yield something like this :

```
  [{"text":"Resources List","language":"en"},{"text":"Список
 Ресурсов","language":"ru"},{"text":"Список Ресурсів","language":"uk"}]
```

The downside of this parsing method that you have to be sure that your "{:}" delimiter is not in your translations.